# Are interpretation and formalization inverse to each other?

Tags: formal-systems

I am not sure if I understand this correctly. Please correct me.

In a formal system,

> an interpretation is a mapping from its formal language to one of its structures
>   ie models.
>
> an formalization is a mapping from  one of its models to its formal
>   language?

So are they inverse processes to each other, in the sense that their domains and codomains are exchanged?

Thanks!

Comment: A formalization of, say, Group Theory cannot reasonably be viewed as a mapping from a **specific** group, say the $1$-element group, to a formal language.  You may be attempting to express everything in terms of the language of sets and functions prematurely. It is useful to first get a lot of concrete experience with concrete cases.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a formalization.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I heard of that word often, such as formalize this thing and that. It sounds like some serious concept but I cant find its definition.

Comment: Not all serious concepts have an honest definition...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the structure that you seek  is the [Galois connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection) between theories and models. A web search on such should turn up many expositions, e.g. in a slightly more general context, see Section 2.2 in  Goguen and Burstall: [INSTITUTIONS: Abstract Model Theory for Specification and Programming.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.78.4047)